# Is the default constructor really necessary for nhibernate to persist an object?

Tags: nhibernate

for some reason I don't wanna let user to create an instance of the object, without sending a property to the constructor
but as I know the object should have default constructor and so it would be possible to create an instance with out sending requierd property.
is there any way to prevent this problem? and if yes does it have any side effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a protected default constructor:

```
public class Product
{
    protected Product() { }

    public Product(Category category)
    {
        this.Category = category;
    }
}
```

Comment: but i think it wouldnt be accesible for nhibernate for its protection level? arent I right?

Comment: NHibernate CAN still access it even if protected. This goes for Properties as well.

Comment: You can add [Obsolete] protected to the nullary constructor to also make sure hand-written code does not use it. This is effectively the same as private.

Comment: I forgot to add that [Obsolete] only works well for sealed entities. Mappable subclasses should be able to call the base [Obsolete] constructor. That will emit a warning, even if they are marked [Obsolete] themselves. You could circumvent that with pragmas, but that's too complicated/error prone for my taste.

Comment: https://github.com/Fody/EmptyConstructor Solves that problem, it invisibly creates default constructor for a class when you don't create one. Consequently, hand-written code won't be able to instantiate an object using the default constructor, that is this won't work `var up = new UserPermission()`. Good for enforcing application not be able to instantiate child entities from hand-written code, that is, only the aggregate root can add child entities.

Answer (score 5):

"NHibernate allows a private default constructor for Value Objects, but for Entities you will need a default public or protected constructor as private is not sufficient."

Here you can find something:

https://github.com/davybrion/companysite-dotnet/blob/master/content/blog/2009-10-why-nhibernate-entities-need-a-public-or-protected-parameterless-constructor.md

Here there's an experiment to work without constructor:

http://kozmic.net/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors/

This is an example working with Dependency Injection:

http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/12/12/entities-behavior-injection.html

Comment: i just used ur suggestion but this error would raise: Castle.DynamicProxy.DefaultProxyBuilder' exists in both 'd:\WebProjects\Azarakhsh.Web\ThirdParty\Castle.Core.dll' and 'd:\WebProjects\Azarakhsh.Web\ThirdParty\Castle.DynamicProxy2.dll

Comment: I completely use http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors.aspx,, I donno if its because of castle dlls?