# Mappings fail to add from assembly

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm struggling with setting up Fluent mappings with NHibernate in a project. With a working project to copy from - I still end up with no mappings and subsequently the exception `FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.`

No clues in either PotentialReasons or InnerException as I gather though...

I've used the suggested method calls from the Fluent documentation and only split them across lines to be able to debug. The call to `BuildSessionFactory` fails, and no xml files are exported in the previous call.

What am I missing? Any ideas or suggestions? Getting more gray hair by the minute...

All these classes live in the same assembly, in different namespaces.

**SessionFactoryCreator class: (part of)**

```
var a = Fluently.Configure();

var cs = MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("AlarmDataDb"));

var b = a.Database(cs);

var d = b.Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Mappings.AlarmData>()
                                .ExportTo(@"C:\"));

var e = d.BuildSessionFactory();
_sessionFactory = e;
```

**Mapping class:**

```
public class AlarmData : ClassMap<AlarmTemp>
{
    public AlarmData()
    {
        Table("PublishOperationMessage");
        Id(s => s.OperationMessageId, "OperationMessageId");

    }
}
```

**DTO class:**

```
public class AlarmTemp : Base
{
    public virtual int OperationMessageId { get; private set; }

}
```

**EDIT**

Stacktrace of the innermost exception (some words are in swedish, but you'll get it):

`vid FluentNHibernate.MappingModel.TypeReference..ctor(Type type)\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.Mapping.IdentityPart.FluentNHibernate.Mapping.Providers.IIdentityMappingProvider.GetIdentityMapping()\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.Mapping.ClassMap1.FluentNHibernate.IMappingProvider.GetClassMapping()\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.BuildSeparateMappings(Action1 add)\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.BuildMappings()\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.EnsureMappingsBuilt()\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.WriteMappingsTo(Func2 writerBuilder, Boolean shouldDispose)\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.PersistenceModel.WriteMappingsTo(String folder)\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentMappingsContainer.Apply(Configuration cfg)\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.Cfg.MappingConfiguration.Apply(Configuration cfg)\r\n   vid FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration()`

Comment: does it have an inner exception?

Comment: Yes, but the message is the one I provided above. I have a stack trace, will edit the question if it helps.

Comment: A couple questions: What are the properties of your base class? Assuming web application, what user account is the site running against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is so weird. I googled the stacktrace message and ended up on this page:

http://geekswithblogs.net/rupreet/archive/2005/12/21/63740.aspx

So, desperate to do anything, I quit VS, deleted the bin folders, restarted VS and built. Guess what - it works now. :-)

Comment: well I am happy for you.  Sometimes it just takes a good ol reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a default constructor in **AlarmTemp**.

Comment: Hmm, I don't need that in the other (working) project. Have you experienced some issues when not having a default constructor? (My problem got solved without having that too)

Comment: @Niklas, Yes to my knowledge you do.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186032/is-the-default-constructor-really-nessessary-for-nhibernate-to-persist-an-object .  Also I was seeing ctor in the exception being thrown and noticed there was no default constructor in your AlarmTemp class.  Maybe there is one in your base?

Comment: Interesting. No, Base doesn't have a ctor either. Will keep my eyes open if a problem arises again. Thanks for the follow up!